# I get the error code CHECKOUT__ASYNC_PAYMENT_PROCESS_INTERRUPTED with Saferpay (Worldline) on shopware 6.4

Tags: shopware6

I am working with Shopware 6.4 where we use Saferpay as a payment service. On my local environment everything works fine and I am able to pay online. But on the staging server (infomaniak) when I try to pay online I do not get redirected to the payment page instead I get the following error code:

[https://my.domain.ch/account/order/edit/{{order-id}}**?error-code=CHECKOUT__ASYNC_PAYMENT_PROCESS_INTERRUPTED*](https://my.domain.ch/account/order/edit/%7B%7Border-id%7D%7D**?error-code=CHECKOUT__ASYNC_PAYMENT_PROCESS_INTERRUPTED*)*

Can someone help me fix this?

The hoster and the payment provider could not help me and also did not have any error logs.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can only try to give you some hints where to look, as this question is not really about programming and would be better suited for an issue tracker.

This is a generic error that could originate in numerous issues. Tracking back the origin of the exception from the query parameter, [this line](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/a7bb639b0c00722036449ba335ade178eb40c5ba/src/Core/Checkout/Payment/PaymentService.php#L139) should be the point where the exception is caught.

You should go back and check your logs at `/var/log` within the Shopware directory, as the detailed exception message should have been logged. You should be able to find it by looking for log entries stating the following:

```
An error occurred during finalizing async payment
```

Once you find the corresponding exception message contact the payment provider again and ask them if it could be an error originating on their side.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! And sorry that I was not able to give more detailed information earlier with the error logs. Now I was able to look into the error logs and I had to make a configuration change on the server (allow_url_fopen).